# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] return GET insted POST

Tags: php, post, get

I create a form using post method like that :

```
  <form name="indexFormn" id="indexForm"  method="POST" action="page.php">
  <div class="AdminformDiv">
  <div class="errorbox">
      <?php
      if (!is_array($this->actionErrors)) {
        echo $this->actionErrors;
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:700px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:128px">Amount</td>
                <td colspan="2">$ <?php echo $this->price;?> USD<td     style="width:270px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

.....
```

but the problem is when I do "var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);" in my php code I get all time "GET" not "POST" and really I don't know why?

Comment: are you using the <form> thingie?

Comment: you know, you need to add an <input type=submit element so you can generate a post request by clicking it, right?

Comment: Did you actually *perform* a POST?

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem using Codeigniter's MVC Framework. Here's what I discovered:

My Action attribute in my form did not include the "www" in front of my domain, but my actual URL needed the "www".

i.e. my form had `action="https://mydomain/something"` but if I went to that URL, I noticed my web host added the www to the beginning:  `https://www.mydomain/something`. (I use DreamHost and it's a setting that I had picked)

I hope this is your issue as well - really frustrating to try and figure out, but once I got my action and actual URL to agree on the "www", my request method went from GET to POST.

Answer (score 1):

Basically most HTTP requests are GET requests. and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] evaluates default GET method.

you can use if($_POST) to check if it's a POST. (That's the array with POST data in it. All pages have $_GET set, so if($_GET) won't work to tell if it's a GET)

when you submit your form then you will sure get POST method on "page.php".
try to get method on this page and found.

Answer (score 0):

Following on the answer by @Brian Stork, it is because of some sort of redirection that happens. The redirection can be because of the following:

- HTTPS/HTTP redirection. For example `certbot` activates this if you want. You can change this in your `.conf` file and then `systemctl restart apache2`
- Trailing Slash redirection.
- `www` subdomain redirection
- Other possible redirection ?!

So check for all these. And if you are doing a bot like a Slack bot that sends requests to your app, check what is the exact url they are sending to avoid redirection.