# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] does not work on server

Tags: php, http-post, postman

I use this on the local server:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
   echo "Failed!";
else
   echo "Success!";
```

When I send data with Postman and local server - check is true, but on the hoster server check is false. Php versions and php.ini files are the same. What else can I check?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` on the hosted server and check what it contains. My gut feeling would be that the server might do some redirect (like redirecting non trailing slash in the url to trailing slash, or the other way around). If that happens, the POST request will be redirected, using GET. But that's just a wild guess. You need to do some more debugging.

Comment: It contains string(3) "GET". I use subdomain. Сan this be related?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. You need to find out what actually happens on the server. When you access the url, try access it both with and without a trailing slash and see if it makes any difference. If not, then you should contact the hosting company, since we don't have a clue about the setup.

Comment: @user3783243 I use Postman soft and Unity as client. I use the same settings and data on the local server and it works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it doesn't make any difference. I'll try to contact my hosting company to help with it.

Comment: Oh, I misread part of this

Comment: Might be related https://stackoverflow.com/a/46533548/1218179

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with http. I use https and it works.